# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when assigning Object(Integer) value to Row field of Object(integer) Type

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

```
Dim size As Integer

Dim PivotDatasource As IEnumerable(Of PivotDrillDownDataRow)

for each row as PivotDrillDownDataRow in PivotDatasource 
   row(dataField.FieldName)=row(dataField.FieldName)+size 

next
```

Comment: Where is DataField defined? If you break on that line and check values, what's the value of dataField.FieldName.  I suspect either that is nothing, or  there's no column in row called whatever is set in dataField.FieldName.

Comment: `PivotDatasource` datasource has not been assigned any value. Use the New keyword and add some items to the collection before looping over it.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't getting the null reference on the line where you assign the variable, you're getting it on the line above:

In your code, `PivotDatasource` is null because you have declared it as a variable that holds a certain type of object but you haven't actually given it any value.

This will result in a NullReferenceException when you try to iterate over it. You can't iterate over a variable that is null, because the compiler will (behind the scenes) call on it to provide an enumerator and if it's null that call will fail

The compiler will also have warned you about this before you ran your app (see the green wiggly underline and Warnings window):

[image]

To resolve the problem, ensure that `PivotDatasource` is initialized to a value of some collection of PivotDrillDownDataRow. How you do this will be something that we cannot easily say given the small fragment of cod you've posted